# how to get IWin32Window of form using reflection

Tags: c#, forms, reflection, .net-3.5, non-modal

I have a windows form that I am displaying as non-modal dialog. As a result I am calling the overloaded Show(IWin32Window owner) method on that form. Only problem is that one of the parent forms that I want to use here is not accessible in the project. As a result I want to load it using reflection using something like code below.

```
var frm = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetTypes().Where(f => f.Name == "ParentForm").FirstOrDefault();
```

However this give following compilation errors.

The best overloaded method match for

> 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.Show(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window)'
>   has some invalid arguments
>
> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Type' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window'

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: With reflection, you're getting the `Type` corresponding to `ParentForm`, not an actual `ParentForm` instance.

Comment: is it possible to get it using reflection?

Comment: You cannot get instances using reflection. It is used only for discovering a `Type` and related properties

Comment: To get what, exactly? An existing instance of it, or a new instance of it? The latter is easy, `Activator.CreateInstance(frm)`. For the former, you need to know how to get a reference to it, it [can't just](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433714/c-sharp-reflection-is-it-possible-to-find-an-instance-of-an-object-at-runtime) be done automatically.

Comment: @Tim: For forms, it can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably will want to search through the `Application.OpenForms` collection.

```
Form f = Application.OpenForms.Where(x => x.GetType().Name == "ParentForm").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That's a great idea. By reflection I first searched for the type and then looked for that type in all open forms from the API you mentioned. Problem solved... You are the man!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @PaulSnow: I think I would have called `GetType()` on each Form in the collection, and checked the name.  Getting the name of the type of each form is a bit less work for .NET than getting the name and other metadata of *every* type.  But glad you got it working.