# Get property path from property instance

Tags: c#, reflection

Say we have some code like this:

```
public class FeatureAnalysis
{
    private float errorLevel;
    public float ErrorLevel
    {
        get { return errorLevel; }
        set
        {
            this.errorLevel = value;
            // Something here?
        }
    }

    public int MeasurementTime { get; set; }
}

public class TestStep
{
    public FeatureAnalysis FeatureAnalysis { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public TestStep TestStep { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose we have another class that has a member of type Test. I know it is possible to get the value from `ErrorLevel` using a string like this "TestStep.FeatureAnalysis.ErrorLevel". (I call it the propertypath, don't know if this is the correct term though). The problem I'm facing seems to require to build this string somehow.

We would like to log changes to every property that is somehow under the Test class, or its members, or its members, ... So the path should go up to Test and no further. I'm also thinking of situations where we have "TestStep.FeatureAnalysis[0].ErrorLevel"

I'm hoping that we don't have to pass the 'parent path' all over.

Alternative ideas are more than welcome.

Comment: You can only get [parent](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1524562/1997232) type, but there is [no way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1433714/1997232) to find inside which class instance of this type is used, etc.

Comment: Ok, maybe this was not clear, I don't need the instance. I will check your links. Edit: what you call parent is actully BaseType, the type from which the class inherits, this is not the case here.

Comment: Yes you need instance: `TestStep.FeatureAnalysis[0].ErrorLevel` here `FeatureAnalysis[0]` is an instance of some type. You can log when `ErrorLevel` property is accessed, but there is no way to determine it was an instance (of whatever type) inside `FeatureAnalysis` array.

Comment: No, I need the string. Then by parsing the string and using reflection on the test object I can get to the `FeatureAnalysis[0]` instance. Maybe I made not clear that the Test instance will be available and hence I only need the path up to Test.